# Why does my Python 3 thread not show up every time I call threading.enumerate?

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I have a long running process that I have put on a thread.

```
import subprocess
import threading

def start_process():
  target = subprocess.run(["python3", "workers.py"])
  create_thread(target)

def create_thread(target):

     threads = []
     name = target.__name__

     for t in threading.enumerate():
         threads.append(t.name)

     if name in threads:
         return False # Thread exists

     t = threading.Thread(None, target, name)
     t.start()

     return "Thread Created."
```

I created a function/Flask route to monitor the thread to see if it is active. 
This function is for a UI update.

```
 @app.route("/info", methods=['GET'])
 def worker_info():
     threads = []
     for t in threading.enumerate():
         threads.append(t.name)
     return jsonify({
         "thread_count" : threading.active_count(),
         "ident" : threading.get_ident(),
         "threads" : threads
     })
```

The problem is that the thread name does not always appear when I call `threading.enumerate` via the flask route. Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: How are you running your Flask app? Most WSGI containers use a forking model, so different requests may be handled by different Python processes, and thus the thread may be in a different process and not visible to the one that's handling the request.

Comment: Your `start_process()` makes no sense as currently posted - you are unconditionally running a process from the current thread, and then trying to make a thread out of its return value?

Comment: Thank you Daniel, that answered my question! I'm running Flask via uwsgi on Nginx. I'm very new to threading so I don't exactly know what I'm doing. I think I need to understand the difference between a process and a thread.